# ngModal and data binding in angular2

Tags: angular, data-binding

i am new to angular 2 and i am facing a problem with 2 way data binding which is that the page doesn't load when i use data binding in my html file
html file when i comment [(ngModel)]="myusername" page loads normally but of course no data is binded when i uncomment it page doesn't load ( i imported the FormsModule from @angular/forms module in app.module.ts)

```
<div class="app flex-row align-items-center">
<div class="container">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" style=" margin-
               bottom:2%;width:160px;height:160px;" align="middle" > 


</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-8">

    <div class="card-group mb-0">
      <div class="card p-2">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h1 style="color:rgb(65,146,195);">Login</h1>
          <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
          <div class="input-group mb-1">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            <input   [(ngModel)]="myusername"  name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          </div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6 text-right">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
            </div>
              <div class="col-6">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-2">Login</button>
            </div>

          </div>

           <div class="row" style="margin-top:2%;">
               <div class="col-6 text-right">
                   <p class="text-muted">Already have an account</p>
                </div>  
                 <div class="col-6 ">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-2 ">Register</button>
                </div>

           </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  user={
   name:"b"
   ,pass:"b"
}
myusername:string;
mypassword:string;
constructor() { }

}
```

thanks very much in advance

Comment: can you show your error message and where your component is declared please

Comment: ther is no error messages .the wrong thing is that the page refuses to load on the browser.

Comment: Can you please create a plunk of your code and give us a link?

Comment: @MariamMaher The code you provided seems to load just fine, seems error needs to be elsewhere... http://plnkr.co/edit/XBZI2zmp7Nc2CZSS0b8J?p=preview

Comment: @AJT_82 but when i comment this line everything works fine which means that the error is in this line

Comment: Well, this code works pretty much like it should, so based on that code we cannot help. Please try and reproduce the issue in a plunker, since there does not seem to be any error in the code you have provided :) Usually this is because of the FormsModule not being imported, but that you said you have. But try and reproduce the issue in a plunker. That way we can see more code and perhaps find an issue somewhere :)